# Getting a clickable URL from strings.xml for a share Intent Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio

I've been searching for hours trying to get my share Intent to be a hyperlink to a specific URL. I saw a lot of answers for this for a TextView but none for a sharing intent and I couldn't figure out  how to get the textView answers applied to this.

Basically I want this string

```
<string name="link"><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?blahblah">EatingOut</a></string>
```

to work with

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurant);
    share = getString(R.string.link);
}

    private void setShareIntent() {

    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Eating at "+ title.getText() + " #" + share );

        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I share it, there is no hyperlink to the "share" part. 
I have tried many different suggestions I read here but like I said most were for textViews

edit: tried the TextUtils.concat but still no hyperlink with and without "#"

```
        CharSequence socialShare = TextUtils.concat("Eating at ", title.getText(), " #", share);
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, socialShare );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is when I share it, there is no hyperlink to the "share" part.

You have a few problems here.

First, I am not aware that `<a>` is a valid HTML-style tag that you can use in a string resource.

Second, `getString()` will remove that HTML-style markup, even if it exists.

Third, you are setting the MIME type of your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` to `text/plain`, and HTML is a different MIME type.

---

Given all that, you need to decide whether you are going to share plain text with a URL just in the text (relying upon the "share" recipient to identify the URL and make it useful to the user, if applicable), or if you are going to share HTML (and hope that the "share" recipient doesn't screw it up too bad).

If you are going to share plain text, then change your string resource to:

```
<string name="link">https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?blahblah</string>
```

You will also want to either get rid of the `#` in your concatenated string, or add a space after it, as putting `#` right before the URL may confuse other apps, causing them to not recognize the URL as being a URL.

If you are going to share HTML, you need to change `setType()` to pass `text/html`, then set `EXTRA_TEXT` to be either an HTML-formatted string or a `Spanned` object (e.g., created via `SpannableStringBuilder`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I did try removing the <a> and using [[CDATA[.. ]] in the string and spannable + (Html.fromHtml) as well as changing the setType to text/html but it was still not giving me a hyperlink. I understand the # could throw it off but I did test it without that to be sure that wasn't causing the problem

Comment: @LuzGonzalez: Bear in mind that unless you are using methods on `TextUtils`, any string concatenation removes any `Spanned` formatting, reducing you to plain text (and removing any hyperlinks set up from there).

Comment: @LuzGonzalez: Use [`TextUtils.concat()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#concat%28java.lang.CharSequence...%29) instead.

Comment: Ok I used it but idk if correctly, still have no hyperlink, could you see the edit and tell me if that's the right way?

Comment: @LuzGonzalez: Change the MIME type to `text/html` (see last paragraph of my answer). You might also use `dumpSpans()` on `TextUtils` to see if you are generating your `socialShare` properly.

Comment: When I change text/plain to html, most of the social media sharing icons go away from the drop down menu. Looking up how to use dumpSpans right now

Comment: @LuzGonzalez: "most of the social media sharing icons go away from the drop down menu" -- then just pass a plain text message with a plain text URL in it (no HTML, no `Spanned`), with a `text/plain` MIME type, and let the social media apps do with it as they see fit. Some apps may make that URL be clickable, some won't. That is their decision to make.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, I did end up letting the social media apps decide